# How to create a new "shared" group in a single SELECT query in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to group a SELECT like you'd normally do - AND at the same time make a new "shared/aggregate group" adding that to the original result-set without a secondary SELECT and UNION.

The secondary SELECT and UNION is out of the question since the real use of this is with some very big tables, with a lot of joins, so it would be waay to slow. So the UNION way is definitely out of the question.

I've tried my best to illustrate this with the following simplified example:

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    id      INT,
    name    VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (1,'cola');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (2,'cola');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (3,'cola');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (4,'fanta');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (5,'fanta');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (6,'fanta');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (7,'water');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (8,'water');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (9,'water');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (10,'cola');
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (11,'cola');

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN name = 'cola' OR name = 'fanta'
            THEN 'soda'
        ELSE
            name
    END as name,
    COUNT(distinct id) as count
FROM #MyTable
GROUP BY name

ROLLBACK TRAN



Actual output:

soda    5
soda    3
water   3

Desired output:

cola    5
fanta   3
soda    8 <- this is the "shared/aggregate group"
water   3
```

Comment: That's called rollup, not a "shared group". If you group by two or more fields you can specify the `WITH CUBE` or `WITH ROLLUP` option. The problem with your query is that you try to generate categories in the query itself. It's *far* easier to do what every data mart does and use a separate `Product` category that contains your hierarchies, eg: Cola/Soda, Water/Other. Grouping by multiple levels becomes as easy as joining with the Product table and grouping by category, product `WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: Thanks.The problem is that it's an old database which is poorly designed. The real life example consists of many joined table, which is why I wrote that multiple SELECT queries is not an option here. Would you happen to know how to make the example work using CUBE or WITH ROLLUP?

Comment: As I already described, create a new dimension table and join with it. There's no way you can get good performance if you put the `CASE` block in GROUP BY - each query will have to scan the entire table to determine the category. Even if you tried to use your original query as a subquery and group by category, the end result would be the same - a full table scan. Joins on string fields are ugly, but better than a full scan

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. I definitely cannot hardcode all the "groups" in the real SQL. That needs to be dynamically, like it is with "group by". I just need that extra group, which is basically consisting of 2 other groups gathered in 1. Is is possible for you to modify my example script with the solution you propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Panagiotis Kanavos correctly pointed out in the comment above, this can be done using ROLLUP:

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #BeverageType
(
    name    VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #BeverageType VALUES ('Soda');
INSERT INTO #BeverageType VALUES ('Other');

CREATE TABLE #UserBeverage
(
    id      INT,
    name    VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (1,'cola');
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (2,'cola');
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (3,'cola');
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (1,'fanta'); -- <- NOTE: user 1 drinks both cola and fanta so the as intended the user is only counted 1 time in the ROLLUP 'Soda' group (7)
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (5,'fanta');
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (6,'fanta');
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (7,'water');
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (8,'water');
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (9,'water');
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (10,'cola');
INSERT INTO #UserBeverage VALUES (11,'cola');

SELECT ub.name, bt.name AS groupName, COUNT(distinct id) as uniqueUserCount
FROM #UserBeverage as ub
JOIN #BeverageType as bt
ON CASE
    WHEN (ub.name = 'water')
        THEN 'Other'
    ELSE
        'Soda'
    END = bt.name
GROUP BY ROLLUP(bt.name, ub.name)

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Outputs:

```
cola    Soda    5
fanta   Soda    3
water   Other   3
NULL    Other   3
NULL    Soda    7
NULL    NULL    10
```

Answer (score 0):

You should repeat CASE statement everywhere.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN name = 'cola' OR name = 'fanta'
                    THEN 'soda' ELSE name END as name,
    COUNT((CASE WHEN name = 'cola' OR name = 'fanta'
                    THEN 'soda' ELSE name END)) as count
FROM #MyTable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN name = 'cola' OR name = 'fanta'
                    THEN 'soda' ELSE name END


+-------+-------+
| name  | count |
+-------+-------+
| soda  | 8     |
+-------+-------+
| water | 3     |
+-------+-------+
```

Can I suggest to use a subquery:

```
SELECT name, count(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'cola' OR name = 'fanta'
             THEN 'soda' ELSE name END as name
      FROM #MyTable) x
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: I actually had done that (the first example) in my own SQL, but the real problem is that I also need both 'cola' and 'fanta' in addition to 'soda'. That's the nut we're trying to crack!

Comment: The subquery will still result in a full table scan to generate the "category" values

Comment: I need 5 colas and  3 fantas in addition to the 'soda' group which consist of both. That's the hard part :-)

Comment: I can, but I'd rather not - only if there's no other way to do this with decent performance.

Comment: Is there a presentation layer? Can you solve it there?

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately this needs to be done in the SQL. In the real code it is the amount of unique users (user count). So I cant just summarize the count of fanta and cola, since the theres no way to use "distinct userid" on those counts.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the aggregate as well as the individual products, then an alternative may be to use a UNION and select the aggregates as a second query.

SELECT name, count(distinct id) as count
FROM #MyTable
GROUP BY name

UNION

SELECT 'SODA',  COUNT(distinct id) as count
FROM #MyTable
WHERE name = 'cola' or name ='fanta'

You might also use Søren Høyer Kristensen's summary table to get the aggregate names if you need more groupings.